# Disable ELMAH in configuration

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, elmah

I've configured ELMAH in my ASP.NET MVC 4 application. I've written some code in the `Application_Error` event to check the status code of the error and invoke an error controller to return appropriate view for 404, 500 errors.

Elmah logs the error if it reaches `Application_Error`. Instead of allowing ELMAH autmatically doing that I want to do trigger it manually from the `Application_Error`. So, is there any configuration property i can set in web.config to disable elmah automatically logging the errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

**Global.asax.cs:**

```
 protected void ErrorLog_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LoggingEnabled"] == "0")
            {
                e.Dismiss();
                return;
            }

            var httpContext = e.Context as HttpContext;
            if (httpContext == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var error = new Error(e.Exception, httpContext);
            ErrorLog.GetDefault(httpContext).Log(error);
            e.Dismiss(); 
        }
```

**web.config:**

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="LoggingEnabled" value="1"/>
  </appSettings>
```